# Why map function in ES6 is not refreshed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to create a ToDo list, It store tasks in `allTasks` state and works when I push manually some data but doesn't show me in map function when I add an item with input.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputValue: '',
            allTasks: []
        }

    this.addToList = this.addToList.bind(this);
    }

    addToList() {
        this.state.allTasks.push(this.state.inputValue);
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
              <h1>کار های خود را مدیریت کنید !</h1>
              <input type="text" placeholder="کار خود را بنویسید ..." onChange={ event => this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value }) } />
              <button onClick={ this.addToList }>ثبت کردن</button>
              <hr />
              <ul>
              {
                  this.state.allTasks.map(task => {
                      return <li>{ task }</li>;
                  })
              }
              </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to update the state with `this.setState(newState)`, rather than manipulating `this.state` directly in `addToList`.

Comment: in addition, you'll want to use `key` props on your `li`s. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @forrert Can you please give me an example, It may help others too.

Comment: @TylerSebastian Is it important to use key certainly ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mutating the original `state`. Dont mutate the state, and use `setState` to rerender the ui.

```
addToList() {
   let k = [...this.state.allTasks];
   k.push(this.state.inputValue);
   this.setState({allTasks: k})
}

or
addToList() {
   this.setState({allTasks: [...this.state.allTasks, this.state.inputValue]})
}
```

Directly changing the state does not rerender the ui. You should avoid mutating state directly. Also using `setState` to update the state will rerender the ui.

`let k = [...this.state.allTasks];` creates a new array, and then we push a value to `k`. So in this case we are not mutating the state directly. Instead we are changing a newly created array. After that we are using `setState` to set the `state` which will update the ui.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell me what happend exactly ? I'm confused.

Comment: @AliBahaari In React, you should never update state directly. Check out https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly for more info

Comment: you might as well combine the two ops, `const k = [...this.state.allTasks, this.state.inputValue]`

Answer (score -1):

Here goes your answer:

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          inputValue: '',
          allTasks: []
       };

       this.addToList = this.addToList.bind(this);
   }

   addToList(e) {
      if( e && e.preventDefault ) e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
         allTasks: [...this.state.allTasks, this.state.inputValue]
      });
   }

   render() {
       return (
         <div>
             <h1>کار های خود را مدیریت کنید !</h1>
             <input type="text" placeholder="کار خود را بنویسید ..." value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={ event => this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value }) } />
             <button onClick={ e => this.addToList(e) }>ثبت کردن</button>
             <hr />
             <ul>
                {
                   this.state.allTasks.map(task => {
                     return <li>{ task }</li>;
                   })
                }
             </ul>
         </div>
       );
   } 
}
```

Here this.setState updates the state and [...allTasks, this.state.inputValue] appends the inputValue to the array of allTasks.
The changing in state makes the component rerender it and hence the updated value will be visible in your list.